# how do I output am EE html template as a json file

Tags: templates, json

how do I output am EE html template as a json file so it validates?
Error:Invalid media type, expecting application/json.

I have tried enabling php to my template and adding the following code after all my data is parsed

But I get this in the output: {!-- ra:000000006fa9a5900000000053584a0b --}[
and the file will not validate.

BUT  if I copy and paste the outputted data into a json validator it validates.  My only issue is the media type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, you could go with the HTTP header plugin, but the same developer (Rob Sanchez) has also made a [JSON plugin](https://github.com/rsanchez/json) that allows for many more JSON specific settings.

If you are looking to install this to EE3, you'll need to make a couple of changes to the plugin files as the plugin itself was made for EE2.  However the changes take less than 5 minutes to do. Check the GitHub issues tab for this info.

Answer (score 2):

Install **"HTTP Header"** [Plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header) to set the EE html template as a json.

```
{exp:http_header content_type="application/json"}
```